# What holds up Windows 10 from loading when my external HDD plugged in USB

Tags: windows-10, boot

If I unplug my external HDD from a USB 3.0 Windows loads in 20 ish seconds. 
If I keep my external HDD connected from a USB 3.0 Windows loads in 50 ish seconds as it wait for 30 seconds before the spinner even starts. The HDD light is dark for the whole time it does nothing. Fresh install of Windows10 same.

Is there a tweak I can change to get it to skip whatever it seems to be waiting for?

Windows10 64 home edition, i7 16GBram GTX1060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be problem with boot sequence. Pc trying to boot from your external hard drive. You need to change boot order in your bios to solve this problem. You have to make your enternal hard disc as first boot device. 
It will solve your problem.